# Send httpdata when pressing a button?

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

How do I put the "try" within an onclicklistener so when I press a button it will send the data? However I do it, it always crashes when I run it.

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);

     name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
     pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

     b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);



         HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www2.park.se/~ts5124/receive.php");
         try {
             JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

             json.put("name","Tim");
             json.put("password", "hje");

             StringEntity se;
             se = new StringEntity(json.toString());

             // Add your data
             httppost.setEntity(se);
             httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
             httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");


             Log.i(TAG, json.toString());

             // Execute HTTP Post Request
             httpclient.execute(httppost);

         } catch (JSONException je) {


         } catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         }

 }
```

I've done buttons before and it has worked, why is there a problem when it is a "try" within the onClick?

Comment: It would help if you added details on what exception you're getting and a stack trace to what line.

Comment: @Runkeball : Please upload the log stack trace also .

Comment: I've posted it under the answer.

Answer (score 2):

you need to add click listener on your button and then put all the http request stuff inside its onClick method:

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Comment: Yes but when I do the app crashes. I take everything from the declaration of HttpClient to the last } after the catch. But still it crashes before I even get to see the buttons and all.

Comment: whats wrong in your `se.saxman.Json.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)`? what code is here (at line 36)?

Comment: b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

Comment: seems like your button **b1** is null. Is `R.id.btn` available in `R.layout.main`? If yes then **Clean** your project and build again.

Comment: Yes it is available, if it wasn't eclipse would've shown an error. Tried to clean it but no further success.

Comment: Eclipse will not show you error if id.btn is not available in layout.main. Because that id may be available in some other layout and you are only referencing it from the **R** file which contains all the ids together. Paste your full activity code in pastebin and provide the url.

Comment: your code seems fine to me. Anyhow, move your entire onClickListener in `if(b1 != null){ /* move listener here */ } else{ Log.w("b1", "is NULL"); }`. I still think your button is null

Comment: and if possible, move *HttpClient* and *HttpPost* inside **try** block too

Comment: It didn't log b1 as null, but still it crahes. Also, i moved HttpClient and HttpPost inside try but didn't matter.

Comment: Yes it says b1 is null, sorry. But still, how can it be that?

Comment: i'm sure you must be doing something wrong with your layout and activity class. Paste your layout (**main**) in your question too

Comment: http://pastebin.com/CFbeXNaW here's the layout. I can't see anything wrong with it but I've stared at it so many times that I've probably gotten blind.

Comment: you are declaring your views' IDs totally wrong! instead of using `android:name="@+id/btn"` you should use `android:id="@+id/btn"` and so on with your EditTexts. No wonder your views were NULL.

Comment: Lol, how crazy. Feeling kinda stupid right now but I've learned some about debugging and nullpointers, so thank you for that and tanks for finding the solution! :)